# Can't load statics Django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

Project structure:

```
project_folder
├── apps
│   ├── app1
│   ├── app2
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── images
│   └── js
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
├── templates
│   ├── base
│   │   ├── base.html
```

Here is my settings.py:

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    STATIC_PATH,
]
```

I got this response:

```
[10/Dec/2017 02:43:58] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1676
[10/Dec/2017 02:43:58] "GET /static/images/Logo-ISCAV.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1676
[10/Dec/2017 02:43:58] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1670
[10/Dec/2017 02:43:58] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1670
```

And here are some tags in the HTML

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-CL">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ISCAV | {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <!-- Carga el path de los archivos estaticos y estilos -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    {% block extrastatic %}
    {% endblock extrastatic %}
</head>
```

I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: Are you serving the website in development with `./manage.py runserver` or on a production server?

Comment: running on DEBUG with PyCharm, searching i find that is an usually problem on this IDE. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help but maybe try adding  STATIC_ROOT

This is always my method..

Without it, It will use the app directory as root,  rather than the project root  :)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), 
)
```

Comment: omg, thx! that's finally work !, Searching deep I think is an usually problem using PyCharm

Comment: Without it, It will use the app directory as root, rather than the project root :)